# Display only the working hours in the liferay 7.4 calendar portlet

Tags: javascript, java, calendar, liferay, liferay-7.4

I'm using Liferay 7.4 GA 24 CE and I want to change the default hours view in the calendar portlet from 24 hours to just working hours (8 am - to 7 pm).

I've looked into the configuration and couldn't find anything related.

How could I change this?

In the Liferay source code, I've examined the scheduler.jsp file to load the calendar hours.

```
    <c:if test="<%= !hideWeekView %>">
        window.<portlet:namespace />weekView = new Liferay.SchedulerWeekView({
            headerViewConfig: {
                displayDaysInterval: A.DataType.DateMath.WEEK_LENGTH,
                eventsOverlayConstrain: '#p_p_id<portlet:namespace />',
                strings: showMoreStrings,
            },
            height: 700,
            isoTime: <%= useIsoTimeFormat %>,
            readOnly: <%= readOnly %>,
            strings: {
                allDay: '<liferay-ui:message key="all-day" />',
            },
        });
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="<%= !hideMonthView %>">
        window.<portlet:namespace />monthView = new Liferay.SchedulerMonthView({
            eventsOverlayConstrain: '#p_p_id<portlet:namespace />',
            height: 'auto',
            isoTime: <%= useIsoTimeFormat %>,
            readOnly: <%= readOnly %>,
            strings: showMoreStrings,
        });
    </c:if>
```

And above code is call js function

```
        const SchedulerDayView = A.Component.create({
            ATTRS: {
                navigationDateFormatter: {
                    validator: isFunction,
                    value(date) {
                        const instance = this;

                        const scheduler = instance.get('scheduler');

                        return A.DataType.Date.format(date, {
                            format: Liferay.Language.get('a-b-d-y'),
                            locale: scheduler.get('locale'),
                        });
                    },
                },

                syncCurrentTimeUI() {
                    const instance = this;

                    const scheduler = instance.get('scheduler');

                    const currentTime = scheduler.get('currentTime');

                    instance._moveCurrentTimeNode(currentTime);
                },
            },

            EXTENDS: A.SchedulerDayView,

            NAME: 'scheduler-day-view',
        });

        Liferay.SchedulerDayView = SchedulerDayView;

        Liferay.SchedulerWeekView = A.Component.create({
            ATTRS: {
                headerDateFormatter: {
                    validator: isFunction,
                    value(date) {
                        const instance = this;

                        const scheduler = instance.get('scheduler');

                        return A.DataType.Date.format(date, {
                            format: Liferay.Language.get('a-d'),
                            locale: scheduler.get('locale'),
                        });
                    },
                },

                navigationDateFormatter: {
                    validator: isFunction,
                    value(date) {
                        const instance = this;

                        const scheduler = instance.get('scheduler');

                        const locale = scheduler.get('locale');

                        const startDate = instance._firstDayOfWeek(date);

                        const endDate = DateMath.add(
                            startDate,
                            DateMath.DAY,
                            instance.get('days') - 1
                        );

                        const startDateFormat = Liferay.Language.get('b-d');

                        let endDateFormat;

                        if (DateMath.isMonthOverlapWeek(startDate)) {
                            endDateFormat = Liferay.Language.get('b-d-y');
                        }
                        else {
                            endDateFormat = Liferay.Language.get('d-y');
                        }

                        const startDateLabel = A.DataType.Date.format(
                            startDate,
                            {
                                format: startDateFormat,
                                locale,
                            }
                        );

                        const endDateLabel = A.DataType.Date.format(endDate, {
                            format: endDateFormat,
                            locale,
                        });

                        return [startDateLabel, '&mdash;', endDateLabel].join(
                            ' '
                        );
                    },
                },
            },

            EXTENDS: A.SchedulerWeekView,

            NAME: 'scheduler-week-view',
        });
```